# How to send email with in memory zipped attachments in Python

Tags: python, email, email-attachments, zip, smtplib

There are multiple topics about sending emails with attachments and creating zip in-memory. Still, it took time for me to combine information from different topics to write code that can create in-memory zip and sends it as a mail attachment. The code below is working (Python 2), but I am not sure I did it the most proper way, as I do not completely understand how io.BytesIO works. For example, do I really need zipped_buffer.seek(0) before zipped_buffer.read()? So any suggestions for improvements are welcome.

I am posting below the whole class I created for sending emails, so I will not need to rewrite part of the code creating in-memory zip to run standalone. And, maybe someone will find it useful. Zipping file in-memory done by the function __zip_in_memory and attachment created from data by the function __convert_to_attachment

Whole class code:

```
import sys,os,smtplib,email,io,zipfile
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import Encoders

class sendmail(object):
    #All email data can be set at initialization 
    def __init__(self,mail_from="",mail_to="",subject="",body="",attachments=[],attachments2zip=[]):
        self.subject=subject
        self.body=body
        self.mail_from=mail_from
        self.mail_to=mail_to
        self.attachments=attachments
        self.attachments2zip=attachments2zip
        self.body_lines=[]
        
    def add_body_line(self,line):#If body lines added one by one
        self.body_lines.append(line)
        
    def set_body(self,text):#If all body text set at once
        self.body=text
    
    #Option to reuse the same instance for multiple mails
    #Is it better then creating class instance for each email?
    def new_mail(self,frm,to,sbj):
        self.subject=sbj
        self.body=""
        self.mail_from=frm
        self.mail_to=to
        self.attachments=[]
        self.attachments2zip=[]
        
    def set_subject(self,text):#Option to set subject separately
        self.subject=text
        
    def set_from(self,text):#Option to set from separately
        self.mail_from=text
        
    def set_to(self,text):#Option to set to separately
        self.mail_to=text
    
    #Add file that will be attached to the email
    def add_attachment(self,file):
        self.attachments.append(file)
    
    #Add file that will be zipped in memory and attached to the email
    def add_attachment_zipped(self,file):
        self.attachments2zip.append(file)
    
    #Read file data
    def __read_file(self,file):
        return open(file, "rb").read()
    
    #Read file data and zip in memory
    def __zip_in_memory(self,file):
        filename=os.path.basename(file)
        zipped_buffer = io.BytesIO()
        zf=zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_buffer,"w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zf.write(file, filename)
        zf.close()
        zipped_buffer.seek(0)
        return zipped_buffer.read()
    
    #Convert data to attachment
    def __convert_to_attachment(self,data,filename):
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(data)
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'%(filename))
        self.message.attach(part)
    
    #Create email and send it
    def send(self):
        self.message = MIMEMultipart()
        self.message["From"] = self.mail_from
        self.message["To"] = self.mail_to
        self.message["Subject"] = self.subject
        #message["Bcc"] = receiver_email  # Recommended for mass emails
        self.body=self.body+"\r\n".join(self.body_lines)
        self.message.attach(MIMEText(self.body, "plain",'UTF-8'))
        
        for file in self.attachments:#For each attachment
            data=self.__read_file(file)#Get file data
            filename=os.path.basename(file)
            self.__convert_to_attachment(data,filename)#Attach file to the message
                
        for file in self.attachments2zip:#For each attachment that need to be zipped
            data=self.__zip_in_memory(file)#Get zipped data
            filename="%s.zip"%(os.path.basename(file))
            self.__convert_to_attachment(data,filename)#Attach file to the message
        
        text = self.message.as_string()
        #Send the email
        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        server.sendmail(self.mail_from, self.mail_to, text)
        server.quit()

#Send test email
if __name__=="__main__":
    import getpass
    username=getpass.getuser()
    m=sendmail()
    m.new_mail(username,username,"Test mail")
    m.add_attachment(__file__)
    m.add_attachment_zipped(__file__)
    m.add_body_line("Hi Alex,")
    m.add_body_line("*** This is an automated message - please do not reply ***.")
    m.add_body_line("Best regards.")
    m.send()
```

Comment: *"For example, do I really need zipped_buffer.seek(0) before zipped_buffer.read()?"* - That's one of those questions... when you don't do that, does it still work? If it doesn't, then you really need to do it, otherwise you don't. :)

Comment: If you have full working code, and want to know whether it could be improved, then you should better post it in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, THanks. I didn't know it exists. Would it be appropriate to post also in CodeReview, or I need to delete this post?

Comment: You have not got any answer for 2 hours... IMHO you can safely delete it and give a try to CodeReview. If you have no luck there, it would be time to post again here explaining that you have already tried CR.

Comment: I will leave it in both places for a day or so and then will delete one depending on the answers.